# How to lookup the Geolocation field?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have two lists list1 & list 2. List 1 contains lookup columns of list2 columns. I want to create a view for list1. In list2 I have geolocation field,but I am unable to lookup to list1. How to lookup the Geolocation field?

Please help on this. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: Kindly post your resolution here if you found any..

Answer (score 0):

The `geolocation` columns are as quirky as **managed metadata columns**, not very well baked. The fact that you have to jump through the hoops you do even to enable them is crazy.

The fact that you **can’t use them in a lookup column** is par for the course, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i need solution.

Comment: You can use the script to get those column's data in your form (Newform & Editform) & set them to desired field.

Comment: You can not directly use **geolocation** columns as lookup. This is the only answer of your question as you wanted it to use them as lookup

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I think I gave you the answer for your problem which you already mentioned in your question. So Kindly accept it if it helps you anyhow. Thanks.. :)

Comment: Kindly post your resolution here if you found any...apart from the description given into my answer... so it will be useful to others

Comment: Respond here with your resolution, If you found any, apart from given answer. So others can get benefit of it.